# React native Button not working when i tap it on my mobile using expo application

Tags: react-native

I am having a problem with my button. i have just started learning reactnative.

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React,{ useState } from 'react';
import { Button, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState('Hamza');
  const clickHandler= () => {
    setName('Awais');
  };
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text >My Name is { name }</Text>
      <Text></Text>
      <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
        <Button title='update State' onPress={ clickHandler }/>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  buttonContainer:{
    marginTop:20,
  },
});
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Comment: I copied your code and tried it using expo snacks and it looks like it's working (https://snack.expo.io/@kickofflive/11792e). It's updating the name when clicking the button, is that what you are trying to achieve? Maybe you have an issue outside the code you supplied here?

Comment: Thanks it automatically worked :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way

```
<Button title='update State' onPress={() => clickHandler() } />
```